# Using Join to include all the rows in accordance with the filter WHERE

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm looking for the SQL string to use in MS-ACCESS that let me to generate Table C

```
        Table C
          "Sector"  "BB_Allocation"           "totSum"                                  
            0       "North America"            "0,5"
            0       "Western Europe"           "0,5"
            0       "Asia Pacific"              ""
            0       "South & Central America"   ""
            0       "Africa / Middle East"      ""
```

Where the field BB_Allocation list all the regions even if there is not value

> Taking the values form:

```
Table A
    "ID"    "isin"          "fldName"                           "blkName"           "fldValue"
    186999  "IE00B4WXJD03"  "HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION"  "North America"     "0,5"
    187000  "IE00B4WXJD03"  "HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION"  "Western Europe"    "0,5"
    ....     other isin      other fldName                      other blkName       other fldValue
```

AND

```
Table B:

    "ID"  "Bloomb_Blk"                     "Bloomb_Allocation"      "BB_Allocation"
    1     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  North America            North America
    2     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Western Europe           Western Europe
    3     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Asia Pacific             Asia Pacific
    4     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  South & Central America  South & Central America
    5     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Africa / Middle East     Africa / Middle East
    6     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Government               Government
    7     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Corporate                Corporate
    8     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Mortgage                 Mortgage
    9     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Preferred                Equity
    10    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Municipal                Government
    11    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Equity                   Equity
    12    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Cash and Other           Cash and Other
    ..    ...................               ............              ...............
```

I First tried with:

```
        strSQL = "SELECT 0 AS Sector, B.BB_Allocation, IIF(IsNull(Sum(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue)))),0,Sum(Format(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue))&'', '#,##0.00'))) AS totSum  " & _
        "FROM A as S " & _
        "RIGHT OUTER JOIN B AS B " & _
        "ON S.blkName=B.BB_Allocation " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "(S.isin='IE00B4WXJD03' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION' )" & _
        "GROUP BY B.BB_Allocation "
```

But I get only:

```
    "Sector"            "BB_Allocation"     "totSum"                    
    "0"                 "North America"     "0,5"
    "0"                 "Western Europe"    "0,5"
```

Then I tried to insert in the WHERE condition "OR S.fldName IS NULL":

```
   strSQL = "SELECT 0 AS Sector, B.BB_Allocation, IIF(IsNull(Sum(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue)))),0,Sum(Format(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue))&'', '#,##0.00'))) AS totSum  " & _
    "FROM A as S " & _
    "RIGHT OUTER JOIN B AS B " & _
    "ON S.blkName=B.BB_Allocation " & _
    "WHERE " & _
    "(S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
    "AND " & _
    "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' )" & _
    "OR S.fldName IS NULL " & _
    "GROUP BY B.BB_Allocation "
```

But I get :

```
  "Sector"  "BB_Allocation"           "totSum"                                  
    0       North America"             "0,5"
    0       Western Europe"            "0,5"
    0       Asia Pacific"               ""
    0       South & Central America"    ""
    0       Africa / Middle East"       ""                                  
    0       Government         
    0       Corporate                
    0       Mortgage                 
    0       Preferred                
    0       Municipal                
    0       Equity                   
    0       Cash and Other
```

Comment: Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.